# Flask app gives a " 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername' " error

Tags: python, sqlite, nginx, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I got a VPS and I wanted to host my flask app there. I followed [DigitalOcean's](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial on "How To Serve Flask Applications with Gunicorn and Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04" (I didnt get the VPS from DO) and everything worked fine with the example app... when I tried to replace the files with my app's files and host the app again I get a 500 error. The 500 error doesnt appear everywhere. It comes up where my .db file is envoled like where I have posts or users etc.. Everything else loads up fine. The layout.html, footer, nav, static files and all that is there.

I already tried rebooting the server, checking env vars reloading nginx etc.. but nothing works.

When I run `sudo systemctl status appname` on terminal I get the following message

```
gunicorn[971]:     return self.get_engine()
gunicorn[971]:   File "/home/apost/atapazar/atapazarvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 
gunicorn[971]:     return connector.get_engine()
gunicorn[971]:   File "/home/apost/atapazar/atapazarvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 
gunicorn[971]:     options = self.get_options(sa_url, echo)
gunicorn[971]:   File "/home/apost/atapazar/atapazarvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 
gunicorn[971]:     self._sa.apply_driver_hacks(self._app, sa_url, options)
gunicorn[971]:   File "/home/apost/atapazar/atapazarvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 
gunicorn[971]:     if sa_url.drivername.startswith('mysql'):
gunicorn[971]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'
```

I'm assuming it's a probelm with SQLite. The site should load the .html files that contain .db info.

Edit: Already checked the other question's here on Stack and even looked on Github but didnt find a solution.
Also when I run the app on my local machine the probelm doesnt come up.